# Making Compiler Error while calling a constructor with less than 2 arguments java

Tags: java, class, constructor, compiler-errors

I have 2 Classes. One is Product that represents a product of 2 functions. the other is Multiproduct and it is a SubClass of it. I need to make a compilation Error while calling the MultiProduct Constructor with less than 2 parameters. The 2 constructors using Vargas.The multiproduct can get more than 2 arguments and because of that it necessary to use vargas.the Product will get only 2 paramters and i donnt have to use ther with vargas

It seems to be something like to constructor chaining or Overloading or Overriding.

we can assume that the user send us a function to to the constructor.
Do you have an idea what I can do?
I can't use Exceptions or Compiler.close() or exit()

```
public MultiProduct(Function... functions) {//TODO: repair the constructor below 2 parameters
    super(functions);
}

public MultiProduct(int x) {//Try using Overload doesnt help because of the vargs

}

public MultiProduct() {
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to create a "compilation error" during runtime because, at that point, compilation has already been completed. Why can't you use exceptions? This is a pretty standard occasion where one would use them. If exceptions are unacceptable you should think about restructuring.

Comment: it is a compilation error nothing not runtime Error

Comment: If you need a **compilation** error for less than two args then you need a ctor that takes two args plus var args

Answer (score 0):

Remove the variable args constructor and add the ones needed only.

```
class MultiProduct {
  public MultiProduct(Function a, Function b) {...}
  public MultiProduct(Function a) {...}
  public MultiProduct() {...}
}
```

Comment: I edited the qustion. The  MultiProduct can get more than 2 parametrs and i have to use vargas

Comment: I don't understand why accept more than two arguments if you want to cause it to fail in that case. Can you explain it?

Comment: The class has a roll and if someone want to build a multi product he can use the constructor. part of the exercise is to make a compilation Error if someone call the constructor with less than 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor like this:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public HelloWorld(int a, int b, int... nums) {
    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld(1);
        new HelloWorld(2, 3);
        new HelloWorld();
        new HelloWorld(1, 2, 3);
        new HelloWorld(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    }
}
```

On compilation I get 2 errors:
[image: Comp errp]

Does this look like what you need?